# Exception is thrown when tried to run a jmeter test having websocket sampler in it , on remote host

Tags: testing, websocket, jmeter, distributed, remote-host

I am trying to run a jmeter test script which has a single websocket sampler.It works fine when i run it from single machine through java GUI or command line.

But , When i try to run it on remote host (by running jmeter-server on other machine) then following exception is thrown.

**ERROR**

```
- jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: JMeter.plugins.functional.samplers.websocket.WebSocketSampler (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled) 
2016/10/06 07:03:20 INFO  - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: Interrupting RMI Reaper
```

Both Master/slave jmeter installations are having same version of jmeter(v3.0) and websocket plugin(v1.0.2).

Any other **http** distributed test runs fine when it is run in same setup.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, it looks like the WebSocket plugin is missing on the remote slave. The main pre-requisite of [distributed JMeter tests execution](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf) is having **the same** JMeter version with the same config, plugins, 3rd-party libraries, etc. on remove slaves as on the master.

So make sure you have **identical** setup on master and all the slaves, i.e. install the [WebSocket Sampler](https://github.com/maciejzaleski/JMeter-WebSocketSampler/wiki) to all the slaves.

- JMeter restart will be required to pick the plugins up
- The easiest way of installing JMeter Plugins and keeping them up-to-date is using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of the requirement of same jmeter and plugin versions. In-fact i took the folder in which plugin is already deployed/installed (A Linux machine) and copied it in to 1 window master machine and 2 linux slave machines.